# Регистрация пользователя администратором(Laravel 5)

Tags: laravel

Ребята, каким способом можно зарегистрировать пользователя администратором. Я пробовал дефолтные методы ларавеля и ничего не получалось. Когда попробовал зарегистировать пользователя не будучи аутентифицированым, то всё сработало. Я так понял по дефолту ларавель не разрешает регистировать пользователей, если в данный момент ты залогинен. Как это можно исправить?
PS: просто у меня в таблице users есть поле role и в зависимости от этого поля юзеры делятся на администраторов и обычных юзеров. Но по идее, юзеров регать должен именно администратор.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию, Laravel не поддерживает роли. Этот функционал вы должны дописать сами. Сейчас у вас как такового нет "администратора", а есть просто залогиненый пользователь с именем 'admin'. У него такие же права, как и любого другого самостоятельно зарегистрированного пользователя.

В теории, нужно сначала создать таблицы `users`, `roles`, `permissions`, `permission_role`, `role_user`. Последние две для связей многие-ко многим, чтобы у каждой роли могло быть несколько пользователей, и у каждого пользователя несколько ролей. То же самое для связи Прав доступа и Ролей. Структуру таблиц показывать тут не буду, очень длинно получится.

В таблице permissions храним имена прав доступа, примерно в виде `user.create`, `user.remove`, `user.edit`. В таблице `permission_role` привязываем права доступа к ролям. В таблице `role_user` связываем пользователя и роли.

После того, как создадите таблицы - добавить связи в модели `User.php`, `Permission.php`, `Role.php`.:

```
/**
 *  File: /app/User.php
 */

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}

/**
 *  File: /app/Role.php
 */

public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
}

/**
 *  File: /app/Permission.php
 */

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

Теперь в модели `User.php` будем перехватывать создание нового пользователя, проверять есть ли такие права у залогиненого сейчас пользователя и разрешать или запрещать ему это действие:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    foreach(Auth::user->roles as $role) {
        foreach($role->permissions as $perm) {
            if ($perm->name === 'user.create') {
                $flight = new Flight;
                $flight->name = $request->name;
                $flight->save();
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Но и после этого пользователя вряд ли получится создать через форму регистрации нового пользователя (проверить не могу, я у себя отключил возможность регистрации пользователей). Вам придется создать собственный `views` с формой регистрации, `controller` для обработки данных формы, и запись в `route.php`, которая будет переадресовывать post-запросы из формы в контроллер, а тот уже будет обращаться в модель `User.php` и производить операции над пользователем.

Как-то так. Пусть меня поправят, я сам laravel5 третий день только ковыряю.

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, за совет. Но, по-моему, Laravel параллельно какие у меня таблицы, отвечающие за роли и как это устроено.
По моей схеме, во время авторизации контроллер обрабатывает данные пользователя, который авторизовался и в зависимости от его роли перенаправляет на отдельный вид. По этому в любом случае обычный пользователь не имеет доступа к функционалу администратора.
Мне кажется, что в Laravel попросту не получится зарегистрировать ещё одного пользователя будучи авторизованным(если мы говорим о AuthController). Поэтому я буду обрабатывать отправку формы в своём контроллере.

Comment: об этом я и говорил, ему все равно на таблицы ролей, потому что из коробки он роли не умеет. при установке он создает для себя только таблицы `migrations`, `users` и  `password_resets`. вот это его, родное. остальное дописывать самому или сторонними плагинами с гитхаба. По-умолчанию для него есть только понятие авторизован пользователь или нет. За это отвечает нативный `Auth`. Для ролей я поставил модуль https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust а админку настраиваю на http://administrator.frozennode.com

Comment: мне кажется, вы не совсем понимаете процедуру регистрации нового пользователя админом. это делается не через форму register, форма register - только для того, чтоб на рабочем сайте была возможность пользователю самостоятельно зарегистрироваться. а регистрация пользователя админом - через админку (самописную или с гитхаба)