# Как сделать регистрацию аккаунтов в laravel не выходя с аккаунта администратора

Tags: php, laravel

Есть задача сделать регистрацию аккаунтов, но что бы это делал админ через админ панелью. Проблема в том что при регистрации происходит сбой, так как стандартная регистрация laravel проверяет не авторизован ли сейчас юзер, и если да то не регистрирует а просто перекидывает на другую страницу. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: добавить условия, если юзер админ то не перекидывать и продолжить региcтрацию

Comment: А где это условие написать? В каком контроллере? Я использую не собственный контроллер а стандартный метод регистрации laravel(make:auth);

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регистрация пользователя администратором(Laravel 5)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529577/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bclaravel-5)